# Why can't the interval construction argument used to show $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable be used for other infinite sets?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I read the following proof as to why the set of real numbers is uncountable.

Assume that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable. Then we can enumerate $\mathbb{R} = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots\}$ and be sure that every real number appears somewhere on the list. Let $I_1$ be a closed interval that does not contain $x_1$. Next, given a closed interval $I_n$, construct $I_{n+1}$ to satisfy both of the following:

(i) $I_{n+1} \subseteq I_n$

(ii) $x_{n+1} \not\in I_{n+1}$

[image]

Now consider the intersection $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$. If $x_{n_0}$ is some real number from the enumerated list, then $x_{n_0} \not \in I_{n_0}$, so $x_{n_0} \not \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$. But we assumed the list contained every single real number, so this implies $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n = \emptyset$. However, the Nested Interval Property asserts that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n \neq \emptyset$, hence the contradiction.

---

**Question:** I don't see why this same argument can't be applied onto $\mathbb{Q}$ and show that the set of rationals is uncountable (which is of course nonsense), or even more generally, show that *any* infinite set $S = \{s_1, s_2, s_3, \cdots \}$ is uncountable, by using the same construction of intervals used above.

Comment: Does $\Bbb Q$ have the Nested Intervals Property?

Comment: I thought about that, but what does it mean that $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have the Nested Interval Property?

Comment: That the intersection may perfectly well be empty, @TrueTears ?

Comment: $[\sqrt2, \sqrt 2+1/n]\cap\Bbb Q$, $n\in \Bbb N$ gives you a nested sequence of closed intervals of $\Bbb Q$. But the sequence has empty intersection.

Comment: Ah okay, so basically the Nested Interval Property states that the non-empty intersection must consist of at least a real number, so it may well be possible that the intersection is empty if we were restricted to only the set of rationals. Correct?

Comment: Yes @TrueTears, though in this case the NIP states that the intersection *is exactly* one single point.

Comment: Thank you both for the explanations.

Comment: @DavidMitra What exactly would mean " a nested sequence of closed intervals of $\mathbb Q$"? how are notions of openness and closedness defined when we are in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin: we don't really need concepts of closed and open sets. Only the notion of closed interval is required here and if $a, b$ are rational with $a<b$ then "rational closed interval" $[a, b] $ is the set of all rational $x$ with $a\leq x\leq b$. Everything apart from completeness of $\mathbb {R} $ has a counterpart in $\mathbb{Q} $ and all usual stuff of analysis can be developed in $\mathbb{Q} $. This will miss all the theorems based on completeness and therefore  be a totally uninteresting  system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closed interval in $\mathbb R$ is an example of a *compact set*. Let $C$ be a compact set and let $\mathcal F$ be a set of closed sets in $C$. Suppose that for every finite subset $F\subseteq \mathcal F$, $\bigcap F\ne\varnothing$. Then in fact $\bigcap \mathcal F\ne \varnothing$. A non-degenerate closed interval in $\mathbb Q$ is *not* compact.

Answer (score -1):

It has to do with topological properties of $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, we take adventure of the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is totally ordered.

If we let $X$ be any topological space, that doesn't have a total ordering on it, then $\forall x,y$ we don't have a well defined notion of $x<y$, so the idea of an interval doesn't make sense. A simple example is $\mathbb{C}$ which cannot be made to be totally ordered.